# Bash file, pass the parameter to firebase command

Tags: bash, firebase, firebase-cli

Hello guys I just want to ask how can I pass the parameters I received in my bash script 
to run `firebase command` with that parameter:

e.g.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  # Get arguments
  deploy=$1
  environment=$2
  token=$3;

  project='iself-dev'
  firebase deploy --only function --project $project --token $token
```

I'm having an error:

```
error: option '--token <token>' argument missing
```

I'm calling the bash script

```
  ./deploy.sh all dev 131434453534
```

Comment: Please try https://shellcheck.net

Comment: That error is suggesting that you didn't actually pass a value to --token.

Comment: Yes I have passed it here: `./deploy.sh all dev 131434453534` in the third argument the 131434453534

Comment: Please put below in script and test `echo  firebase deploy --only function --project $project --token $token`

Comment: @onecompileman : Maybe $3 is empty. I would change the assignement to `token=${3:?3rd parameter empty or missing}`, to catch this error with a more meaningful error message.

Comment: It is always a good idea to embed the parameters into double quotes like `"$project"` or `"$token"`.

Comment: What about if you just export `FIREBASE_TOKEN` ? e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli   Also You're not using `$deploy` - is this correct?